# Why is there a mismatch between show bytecode and class file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, bytecode

### original .java file

```java
public enum Fruit {
    ORANGE(1), APPLE(2);
    private final int i;
    Fruit(int i){
        this.i=i;
    }
}
```

### .class file

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by FernFlower decompiler)
//

public enum Fruit {
    ORANGE,
    APPLE;

    private Fruit() {
    }
}
```

### show bytecode result

```java
// class version 61.0 (61)
// access flags 0x4031
// signature Ljava/lang/Enum<LFruit;>;
// declaration: Fruit extends java.lang.Enum<Fruit>
public final enum Fruit extends java/lang/Enum {

  // compiled from: Fruit.java

  // access flags 0x4019
  public final static enum LFruit; ORANGE

  // access flags 0x4019
  public final static enum LFruit; APPLE

  // access flags 0x12
  private final I i

  // access flags 0x101A
  private final static synthetic [LFruit; $VALUES

  // access flags 0x9
  public static values()[LFruit;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 1 L0
    GETSTATIC Fruit.$VALUES : [LFruit;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL [LFruit;.clone ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    CHECKCAST [LFruit;
    ARETURN
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0

  // access flags 0x9
  public static valueOf(Ljava/lang/String;)LFruit;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 1 L0
    LDC LFruit;.class
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Enum.valueOf (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;
    CHECKCAST Fruit
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE name Ljava/lang/String; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x2
  // signature (I)V
  // declaration: void <init>(int)
  private <init>(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 4 L0
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    ILOAD 2
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Enum.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;I)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 5 L1
    ALOAD 0
    ILOAD 3
    PUTFIELD Fruit.i : I
   L2
    LINENUMBER 6 L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE this LFruit; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE i I L0 L3 3
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 4

  // access flags 0x100A
  private static synthetic $values()[LFruit;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 1 L0
    ICONST_2
    ANEWARRAY Fruit
    DUP
    ICONST_0
    GETSTATIC Fruit.ORANGE : LFruit;
    AASTORE
    DUP
    ICONST_1
    GETSTATIC Fruit.APPLE : LFruit;
    AASTORE
    ARETURN
    MAXSTACK = 4
    MAXLOCALS = 0

  // access flags 0x8
  static <clinit>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 2 L0
    NEW Fruit
    DUP
    LDC "ORANGE"
    ICONST_0
    ICONST_1
    INVOKESPECIAL Fruit.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;II)V
    PUTSTATIC Fruit.ORANGE : LFruit;
    NEW Fruit
    DUP
    LDC "APPLE"
    ICONST_1
    ICONST_2
    INVOKESPECIAL Fruit.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;II)V
    PUTSTATIC Fruit.APPLE : LFruit;
   L1
    LINENUMBER 1 L1
    INVOKESTATIC Fruit.$values ()[LFruit;
    PUTSTATIC Fruit.$VALUES : [LFruit;
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 5
    MAXLOCALS = 0
}
```

Why is there a mismatch between show bytecode and class file?

I looked into how to proceed with the Decompile process in intellij, but I couldn't find any official reference.

I believe the result of show bytecode is not the raw ByteCode. This is because the raw bytecode is not human-readable.

So, as a result of Show bytecode, the decompiled version of the class file is both in processed form. Why is there a discrepancy between the two?

(I also heard that class files are composed of bytecode)

Is this a problem caused by a difference between the decompilation process and the show bytecode process, and the latter being more resilient of the two? (guess)

Comment: From the [FernFlower](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower) GitHub: _"Fernflower is the first actually working analytical decompiler for Java and probably for a high-level programming language in general. ***Naturally it is still under development, please send your bug reports and improvement suggestions to the issue tracker.***"_

Comment: what discrepancy are you referring to? That the generated java code, called "**.class file**", 2nd snippet above, is different than the "**original .java file**"? Or do you mean the difference between the 2nd snippet ("**.class file**") and the last snippet, "**show bytecode result**"? || Mind that what is called "**.class file**" above is actually the decompiled code, not the real .class file content (aka bytecode); neither is the last one, called "**show bytecode result**", is not *just* the bytecode  - it is some representation of bytecode, augmented with additional information

Comment: This refers to the discrepancy between the class file and show bytecode results.

Comment: well, as already written, the 2nd one is not showing bytecode, but as its header states: "*Source code recreated from a .class file*". While the last one is, as explained in first answer, showing bytecode in a more readable form (kind of disassembled)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is there a discrepancy between the two?

If you are asking why there is a discrepancy between ".class file" and "show bytecode result", that is because they are showing different things:

- the former shows the decompiler's attempt to reconstruct source code from the bytecodes.
- the latter shows a disassembly of the bytecodes; i.e. the bytecodes rendered as (an approximation to) bytecode assembly language.  This is designed for people who want to<sup>1</sup> **read the bytecodes** output by the Java compiler with the aid of the JVM spec.

If you are asking why "original .java file" and ".class file" are different, they are (once again) showing different things.

- the former shows the Java source code that you wrote
- the latter shows *reconstructed* Java code, that was generated by the decompiler.  Basically, the original code was compiled to bytecodes, and then it was *decompiled* back to Java source code.  This code may or may not be correct<sup>2</sup>.

---

In this case, the decompiled code is different to the original.  It looks like the decompiler was not able to reconstruct the constructor for the `enum` and its `private int` variable.  That is a *limitation* of the decompiler that Intellij is using.  I imagine that that limitation *could* be fixed<sup>3</sup>.  However decompilers limitations are inherent, and can't be fixed.  These include:

- Decompilers cannot reconstruct the original code layout, javadocs, comments and so forth that are not present in the ".class" file.
- If two different Java source constructs compile to the same bytecodes, the decompiler can't tell which one was used originally.
- Bytecode obfuscators, deliberately do things to the bytecodes to make it harder to reconstruct valid Java source code ... let alone code that is readable.

---

<sup>1 - This is not as useful as you might think.  The "problem" is that bytecodes are (deliberately) not optimized.  Instead the JIT compiler will (eventually) compile + optimize the bytecodes to native code.  Often the transformations performed by the JIT compiler are pretty radical; e.g. inlining methods, optimizing away unnecessary loops, and so on.  This means that supposed performance insights you might get from reading the bytecodes are (at best) unreliable.

2 - It may not be functionally identical to the original code.  Indeed, it may not even be valid Java source code.  There are various reasons for this.

3 - ... if someone is willing to put in the work.  Indeed, it is possible that the problem is already addressed in a (hypothetical) more recent version of the decompiler.</sup>

Comment: That's not a correct analysis.  While the value of `i` cannot be observed using "pure Java" code, you should be able to use reflection to get hold of the `java.lang.Field` for the `i` field and then use that to interrogate `i`s value at runtime.  The decompilation is incorrect.   (If the JIT compiler was somehow able to determine that the field was never access, it could be eliminated *at runtime*.  But that's a different issue.  And ... I don't think it is feasible to even do that.)

Comment: I don't think that this is the decompiler trying to be smart.  I think it is just plain wrong.  But it is not unusual for decompilers to get things wrong.  They are typically implemented as a bunch of heuristics and pattern matches.  They don't have a deep understanding of the meaning of code they are working on.

Comment: Anyway: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-339031

Comment: We have no control over what the OP puts in his Intellij bug reports.  (I assume it was him ... based on the wording and the timing.)

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to as the `.class` file is actually, as the FernFlower comment explains, recreated source code. The `.class` file was run through a decompiler that attempts to convert the bytecode back into its original source code.

The "show bytecode result" code that you pasted is just a readable representation of the contents of the file